# Random number range specification

Tags: java

I want to pick a random number that is -1<x<1, but if I use Math.random, it is only -1<=x<1.

How do I get a random number in this range?

```
double x = (Math.random*2)-1
```

Comment: "but if I use Math.random, it is only -1<=x<1." `0 <= x < 1`, surely?

Comment: OP has already solved "how to generate random numbers within a specific range". This question is about how to exclude endpoints. Not a great dup imo.

Comment: Just discard -1 when (if) you get it?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo what's not "within a specific range" about `-1 < x < 1`?

Comment: Generate a number in the range `0 <= x < 1`; randomly multiply that by -1 or 1.

Comment: @AndyTurner That gives you a higher chance of getting zero. But then, there are two zeroes in floating point, so maybe that's correct.

Comment: @khelwood OP didn't specify the distribution.